# Symfony 2. Route appears to work in CLI but always 404's in browser

Tags: php, xml, symfony

I have been playing around with Docker and Symfony in my spare time trying to get to grips with them. I have got my project to the stage that I can start up Docker and access the Symfony welcome screen... huzzah!

I figured at this point it should be plain sailing so attempted to start adding some routes/controllers etc. So I setup a basic route which will ultimately serve as a login screen, however I can never seem to access it in the browser.

That said I can see that it matches (and should work as far as I am aware) when I run `app/console route:match /login`

[image]

Heres the content of the various files which I have edited/added thus far.

**app/config/Routing.yml**

```
app:
resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

**routing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
    http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

<route id="login" path="/login">
    <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Login:__invoke</default>
</route>
```

**app/config/Services.yml**

```
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value

services:
#    service_name:
#        class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
#        arguments: ["@another_service_name", "plain_value", "%parameter_name%"]
imports:
  - { resource: ../../src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.xml }
```

**services.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <imports>
        <import resource="controllers.xml"/>
    </imports>

</container>
```

**controllers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>

        <service id="controller.login" class="AppBundle\Controller\LoginController">
        </service>

    </services>
</container>
```

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function __invoke()
    {
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Huzzah!</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it seems to me like it should be working instead of the 404 I am currently getting, any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have ACL ? Can you dump the exception thrown and wich generates the 404 ? Maybe the route is OK but something thrown a `NOT_FOUND` error, dumping the exception will give more clues.

Comment: Change the `_controller` in your routing.xml to the service id of your controller: `controller.login`.

Comment: @AlFoиceѫ Excuse my ignorance but what is ACL?

Comment: @cosmicsafari Access Control Layer. If uer is not allowed to access the route, ACL can generate a 403 error. 403 is "Unauthorized access", but often a 404 "Not found" is thrown instead, because the visitor (or hacker) don't have to know the real error cause.

Comment: I also tried @Frasci suggestion but still 404s unfortunately, I assume you meant replace AppBundle:Login:__invoke with controller.login:__invoke ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue appeared to be with who owned the app/log and app/cache Symfony folders. For some reason they where owned by root locally which carried over when I started up my docker containers.

This resulted in Symfony not being able to write to them. Once I changed the owner from root to match the rest of the folders and started up my containers it all worked as expected.